# Java Regex and replaceAll

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text:

> Testlalatest

I am trying to replace `lala` with another string,

Output should be `Test[replace]test` only if there is any char after or behind `lala`.

but I am getting that: `Tes[replace]est`

Code:

```
strLine = strLine.replaceAll("\\w"+word+"\\w", replaceWord);
```

Comment: Why are you using / instead of \ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lookarounds to make sure your word is preceded and followed by a word character on each side.

```
strLine = strLine.replaceAll("(?<=\\w)" + word + "(?=\\w)", replaceWord);
```

Or else use `\B` on either side:

```
strLine = strLine.replaceAll("\\B" + word + "\\B", replaceWord);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uJ7gA3/1)

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String prefix : new String[] { "pre", "" }) {
            for (String suffix : new String[] { "suf", "" }) {
                String toReplace = "lala";
                String before = prefix + toReplace + suffix;
                System.out.println(before + " -> "
                        + before.replaceAll("(?<=.)" + toReplace
                        + "|" + toReplace + "(?=.)", "[replaced]"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
prelalasuf -> pre[replaced]suf
prelala -> pre[replaced]
lalasuf -> [replaced]suf
lala -> lala
```

[Information on the relevant regex syntax.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

As was commented, it's strange that you've written `//w` instead of `\\w` for a word character. I'm not sure how that got replaced before.

Also, you said you wanted to match *any char* which means you want to use `.`, not `\\w`.